# MS Access SQL Select Statement Returns Correct Fields but No Data in the Rows

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, select-query

I have two Microsoft Access database tables. They are named `Historical_Stock_Prices` and `Balance_Sheets`. I need to combine data from each of these tables to create a table called `Daily`. I need to take the fields `Ticker`, `[Date]`, and `[Close]` from `Historical_Stock_Prices` and I need to take the field `Common_Stocks` from `Balance_Sheets`.

I will not be taking every row from the `Historical_Stock_Prices` and `Balance_Sheets` though. I will only be taking the rows that are on or before a date selected in a `DateTimePicker` named `dtpDateSelection`.

Now the main problem that I have is that `Historical_Stock_Prices` contains a row for each day. While `Balance_Sheets` contains a row for each quarter. So for each day in a quarter the figure that comes from `Balance_Sheets` will be the same.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Dim Date1 As Date = dtpDateSelection.Value

Try
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Daily AS SELECT [H].[Ticker], [H].[Date], [H].[Close], [B].[Common_Stocks] FROM [Historical_Stock_Prices] AS [H] INNER JOIN [Balance_Sheets] AS [B] ON Int(Year([H].[Date])) = Int([B].[Year]) AND Int(Format([H].[Date],'Q')) = Int([B].[Period]) AND CStr([H].[Ticker]) = CStr([B].[Ticker]) WHERE CDate([H].[Date]) = #" & CDate(Date1) & "#", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
Dim cmda As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DROP PROCEDURE Daily", con)
cmda.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim cmdb As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Daily AS SELECT [H].[Ticker], [H].[Date], [H].[Close], [B].[Common_Stocks] FROM [Historical_Stock_Prices] AS [H] INNER JOIN [Balance_Sheets] AS [B] ON Int(Year([H].[Date])) = Int([B].[Year]) AND Int(Format([H].[Date],'Q')) = Int([B].[Period]) AND CStr([H].[Ticker]) = CStr([B].[Ticker]) WHERE CDate([H].[Date]) = #" & CDate(Date1) & "#", con)
cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Try
```

This code creates the table `Daily` and the fields `Ticker`, `[Date]`, `[Close]` and `Common_Stocks` within that table.  But the code does not load any data into the rows of the table.  Any ideas why not?

Comment: You're  just creating a stored proc (twice for some reason). You need to actually run it to get results.

Comment: This code creates a query (view) in MS-Access. This code doesn't return anything

Comment: @YuriyGalanter How would I actually run it?

Comment: @Steve How would I return something?

Comment: @gromit1 do you need a stored query? Just Create a new SELECT command as `New OleDbCommand("SELECT [H].[Ticker], ....` and use a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I will only be using `Daily` for future calculations.  Should I create `Daily` every time I do the calculation?  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See @Steve answer below

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your code is do what you need it to do. I don't see a `CREATE TABLE` command that would create the desired tables or a `INSERT INTO` command that would insert the records into the tables.

Comment: I've changed my SQL statement to reflect @Steve answer.  In VB.net the query still returns blank and in MS Access it throws a `Syntax error in SQL expression` message.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're creating a stored procedure that doesn't actually `INSERT` any data into the table `Daily` that you mentioned.

You might want to change the first portion `CREATE PROC Daily AS` to `INSERT INTO dbo.Daily`. That way, the data will be appended to the table.

Comment: I've changed my SQL statement to reflect @Steve answer.  In VB.net the query still returns blank and in MS Access it throws a `Syntax error in SQL expression` message.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to create the equivalent of a View. By itself it doesn't return any data. 
You could return the data from the SELECT statement. Not sure if the syntax is correct but you could try the cmdText directly with MS-Access and verify the results

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT [H].[Ticker], [H].[Date], [H].[Close], [B].[Common_Stocks] " & _
              "FROM [Historical_Stock_Prices] AS [H] INNER JOIN [Balance_Sheets] AS [B] " & _
              "ON Year([H].[Date]) = [B].[Year] AND " & _
              "Format([H].[Date],'Q') = [B].[Period] AND " & _
              "[H].[Ticker] = [B].[Ticker] "
              "WHERE [H].[Date] = ?"
Using cmdb = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, con)
    cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", CDate(Date1))
    Using da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdb)
        Dim dt = new DataTable("Daily")
        da.Fill(dt)
        ' now you have an IN MEMORY DataTable named Daiyly filled with the data '
        ' returned by the SELECT query '
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: When I tried this code I got this error in vb.net `Additional information: Type mismatch in expression.`

Comment: Take the query as it and put in Query designer of MS-Access. Usually you will be able to find the problem (Probably there is a problem with the Format that returns a string and the Period but it is also possible that other fields used in the join or in the where are not of the exact type expected)

Comment: I no longer the error message.  But when I load the `DataTable` into a` DataGridView` the `DataGridView` is blank.

Comment: But the query in MS-Access with the same value for `[H].[Date]` returns rows? Try to convert Date1 parameter in a true DateTime using `Convert.ToDateTime(Date1)`

Comment: The query in MS-Access throws a `Syntax error in SQL expression`.

Comment: I would try to resolve the problem in MS-Access. If you post your db on a shared hosting like skydrive, gdrive or dropbox and post the link here I would give a try.